# Lucene: match fields that begin with a phrase

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

For the following documents (let's assume a single field in every doc): 
1 - A B C D 
2 - A B 
3 - C D A B

(A-D are distinct terms)

I would like to create a query "A B" that only matches documents 1 and 2. I know I can insert a special "beginning of field" token to help me out, but I prefer to avoid that (requires re-indexing all the data, and is also a bit ugly).

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The trick is to combine a [SpanNearQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html) with a [SpanFirstQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanFirstQuery.html).

```
  SpanNearQuery spanNearQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new[] { new SpanTermQuery(new Term(field, "A")), new SpanTermQuery(new Term(field,"B")) },0, true);
  SpanFirstQuery spanFirstQuery = new SpanFirstQuery(spanNearQuery, 2);
```